Pytest errors with Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-Security-too
Completely lost with pytest and these libraries. The app, for whatever I'm able to run locally, works as expected. If I run the tests one-by-one manually, they pass. However, if I just run them all, it all crumbles down.
init.py of the app, trimmed blueprint and other imports.
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    load_dotenv()
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    db.init_app(app)
    login.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    jwt.init_app(app)
    init_db()
    
    if app.config['TESTING']:
        with app.app_context():
            db.create_all()
**            db.metadata.clear()**

    fsqla.FsModels.set_db_info(db)
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    app.security = Security(app, user_datastore)
#etc..
    return app


conftest.py (under /tests/)
import pytest
from flaskr import create_app
from config import TestingConfig


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app(TestingConfig)
    yield app


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()

test_factory.py:
from flaskr import create_app
from config import TestingConfig


def test_config():
    assert not create_app().testing
    assert create_app(TestingConfig).testing

def test_index(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200


User & Role. Straight from the flask-security-too documentation.
class User(db.Model, fsqla.FsUserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    roles = so.relationship('Role', secondary='roles_users', backref=so.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<User {self.email}>'


class Role(db.Model, fsqla.FsRoleMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'role'

The bolded line db.metadata.clear() was added there as without this call the test_config would throw the following error.
This error will also appear if the test runner first passes an, e.g., empty test and then proceeds to the next file.
[undefined]sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'roles_users' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
With this metadata clear place, however, the create_app called through the fixture will now error out when reaching this metadata clear line:
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'roles_users.user_id' could not find table 'user' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
What makes things even puzzling for me at least is that if I run the test_x.py files one by one, they will pass. Also, if I stop the execution and have a peek at the generated database, it looks exactly as it should be. Clearly somehow related to how I handle the flask-security, but just can't get the grasp of what exactly goes south.
TestingConfig is subclass for the Config, merely setting db to in-memory sqlite and TESTING to True.
init_db function includes only imports for models others than those of flask-security. The database handling in development/production is through alembic.
Tried:
Manually run tests one by one. This works.
Review the generated database during tests, looks exactly like the one used in development.
Adding, removing the metadata clear, neither helps really.
Manually defining the roles_users table. This broke down the whole application.

I think the root of your issue is 'yielding' app.app_context(). Have you tried having the 'app' fixture just return the 'app'. While some tests might need to manually setup an app_context - for tests that use 'client' - you don't want an existing app_context since Flask will push another one and you'll never pop back to no context - which means that things stored in 'g' will never get reset. In this model - each test will create a new Flask, new DB, etc.

Edited to the original post, tried both with and without the unnecessary app_context(). Even without, the metadata related error persists.

can you show your DB file?

Apologies, not sure if I had fumbled something earlier and the database appeared not like stated above.
Seems that with the metadata clear in place nothing gets created. Likely expected.
And without the metadata clear the roles_users table will be missing.

Too quick with my comment there. roles_users table is created, however the metadata related errors appear.
What sort of file are you referring with the DB file?

Where is DB initialized, what is 'so' - and 'roles' is already defined in FsUserMixin - so you are redefining it (should be fine). You should not need the metadata.clear() - each test should create a new app and new DB. I assume you are using an in-memory DB

db = SQLAlchemy() was imported from extensions module. so was abbreviation for sqlalchemy.orm. In-memory db was in use.

I resolved this issue by creating a fresh project and adding one module at a time. What seemed to be the issue was the location of the line fsqla.FsModels.set_db_info(db), which originally was in the create_app()-call. I moved it out of of there, succeeded by the User and Role imports, and fixed other attempted "fixes."
